# Is there a specific library to handle the collision system of a big game world like WoW, or any physics library will work?

Tags: collision-detection

Nothing else to add. Is there a specific library to handle the collision system of a big game world like WoW, or any physics library like ODE will work?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a major ongoing purge of these sorts of questions (i.e. ones asking for libraries, which in essence are list-style questions) and so it came up in the review queue for closure.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I'm fine with purging this one, but why would you do that? I mean it seems to be destroying potentially valuable information for what? Freeing HD space?

Comment: Personally, I agree with your evaluation, and have made this same argument, especially for older, higher-voted, high-traffic questions. The problem is that the rest of the mods do not agree, and intend to terminate these questions on principle (which I can understand, as principle is important - if we allow some such questions, new askers will wonder why we disallow others).

Comment: Be a rebel! Fight the system! Heh. BTW, list-style questions are **extremely** useful in practice. I don't understand the problem, it seems like there is this culture here where people love to hate questions that novices tend to make, even when those are actually useful. /shrugs

Comment: You've been here long enough to know this, but... welcome to SE *sigh*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is not to use any physics library at all:

- Collisions with the **environment** can be handled directly by the underlying **[navigation mesh](http://www.ai-blog.net/archives/000152.html)**.
- Collisions with **dynamic objects** could be as simple as **[bounding sphere](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/using_bounding_spheres.htm)** collision checks using some sort of **[space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning)** to limit the amount of checks necessary.

Comment: I don't see how a navigation mesh solves collision detection, you still need a collision mesh and just stating that doesn't say much of anything, because the actual collision checking is complicated.

Comment: @dreta The navigaton mesh defines where you may walk, so by excluding obstacles from the mesh you can no longer walk over them. It's not collision detection but serves the same purpose. It works especially well for games where regular movement requires pathfinding anyay, like graphic adventures and many mmorpgs such as ragnarok online. Hence stating it was an alternative, not a fit for every game.

Comment: Yeah, Ragnarok online's .GAT are a great example. Here's one SS of a Map editor I made once with a .GAT opened: http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9672/20330729.png A .gat file stores the altitude of the cells in the map, and the walkable/unwalkable cells of the map. (in the image, red is unwalkable, green is walkable)

Comment: @Gustavo-Gtoknu That's interesting, I only mentioned Ragnarok Online as an example intuitively from what I still remember of the game, but had no idea how map navigation data was actually stored. :)

Comment: @GustavoMaciel The link to your image shack image is now invalid, you might want to reupload it to stack.imgur server!

Answer (score 2):

Any physics library like ODE will work. Most, if not all, physics libraries will offer a way to divide objects into different 'subspaces', where only objects in the same subspace will collide. How exactly you handle things will mostly depend on how you do all the other 'large world handling'.

Let's put this differently: unless you want to do some extreme world-spanning physics effects, physics are going to be the least of your troubles in doing a big game world.